# Wrong levels after storing character as factor

Tags: r

In my dataframe df I have Likert-Scale items coded 0-4. After importing these from the raw file into R, they were stored as characters.
I then created a list with boolean indicating whether each variable was a character, then used lapply to change it to factor.

```
i <- sapply(df, is.character) 
df[i] <- lapply(df[i], as.factor)
```

When looking at some of the now factor variables (all are originally coded as 0-4), I get:

```
df$reactance1
[1] 3   3   4   3     2   4   1   4   3   3   1   1   4   3   4   3   4   4
Levels:   1   2   3   4 3 4
```

or

```
df$EAI4
 [1] 0   0   2   1     2   0   3   4   1   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
Levels:   0   1   2   3   4 0 1 2
```

I tried to solve the problem with droplevels()

```
df$reactance1 <- droplevels(df$reactance1)
```

My guess is R, for some reason, thinks a character 3 is different from another character 3, although they should be treated identically. This results in too many levels. I checked my raw data to see if there are maybe spaces in front of some of the numbers, but it does not seem like it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check your 'character' columns for leading/lagging spaces i.e. `" 3"` or `"3 "` or `"3"`  If that is the case, all of the three cases will be different levels when you convert to `factor`.

Comment: Thanks. as.data.frame(apply(df,2,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x))) solved it

Comment: I'm confused... How were these stored in the raw file? As numbers or characters? Because if they were stored as numbers but R reads them as characters, then you may want to change some parameters in your import code.

Comment: However, now I cannot change variables from factor to character to numeric... If I try to change character to numeric, it changes it to factor automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a case of `leading/lagging` spaces in the 'character' columns.  We could remove those spaces with `trimws` (`base R` function) if the `class` of the column is `character`and convert them to `factor` or `else` leave the column as such.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(is.character(x)){
              factor(trimws(x))
              } else x
        )
```